# VB How do i convert series of TAB-delimited ASCII codes to their equivalent CHARs

Tags: vb.net, ascii

(Visual Basic)

Let's say I have a string that contains, for example, the following:

```
72  101 108 108 111 32  33
```

The question is, how do i loop trough those (tab-delimited) numbers in order to convert each one to the CHAR value it represents (which, in this case, is "Hello !").

Comment: Which part are you struggling with? Splitting the string on the delimiters, or converting ASCII codes into characters?

Comment: Both. I'm beginner in VB, and I managed to create the function that converts a string into tab-delimited numbers (which ofc represent each chars ASCII value) but I cannot seem to know how to make the one that 'converts' the string back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Imports System.Text
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        ' Your initial input string
        Dim x As String = "72" & vbTab & "101" & vbTab & "108" & vbTab & "108" & vbTab     & "111" & vbTab & "32" & vbTab & "33"

        ' The object that will store your final word
        Dim FinalWord As New stringbuilder

        ' Loop through your input string and convert each ASCII code to a character
        For Each Code As String In x.Split(vbTab)
            FinalWord.Append(Chr(CInt(Code)))
        Next

        '..... Do whatever you wnat with your "FinalWord"
    End Sub

End Module
```